# epoch time conversion

Tags: php

how can I convert this epoch time to human readable date time

```
1331515367
```

I used the following code but this gives me the current time in my zone

```
$time = 1331515367
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```

thannks

Comment: What timezone do you want it in?

Comment: Maybe because the timestamp 1331515367 *is* the current time, or at least used to be at the time of writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates generated on your server are going to be in whatever time zone your server says to use.  If you want to change it use: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

```
date.timezone ="timezone";
```

For a list of time zones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

All of this was found using this google search: php date timezone
https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+date+timezone